# Kafka Schema Registry Unable to Register Schema - Register schema request failed since master is unknown

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I have a docker container running the `confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.0` image in AWS Elastic Container Service (Fargate). Only one container is running. API calls to get currently registered schemas through this schema registry are working (e.g. `GET http://<schema-registry-url>:8081/subjects`).  If I try to register a schema that matches a current subject's definition (e.g. `POST http://<schema-registry-url>:8081/subjects/<my-subject>/versions`) I get the current subject's ID returned.  However, if I try to register a brand new subject (e.g. POST `http://<schema-registry-url>:8081/subjects/<my-subject-that-doesn't-exist-yet>/versions`) I get a 500 exception and a message as follows:

```
{
    "error_code": 50004,
    "message": "Master not known."
}
```

Trying to delete existing schema versions likewise fails.  Logs from the docker container show the following:

```
[2021-01-15 22:09:57,855] ERROR Request Failed with exception  (io.confluent.rest.exceptions.DebuggableExceptionMapper)
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.exceptions.RestUnknownMasterException: Master not known.
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.exceptions.Errors.unknownMasterException(Errors.java:114)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource.register(SubjectVersionsResource.java:281)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:159)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.serviceImpl(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:502)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.UnknownMasterException: Register schema request failed since master is unknown
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.registerOrForward(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:546)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource.register(SubjectVersionsResource.java:263)
    ... 59 more
```

This is in a deployed environment.  A local docker container on my machine with the same environment variables as the deployed version will successfully register new schema subjects.

Answer (score 0):

I killed the Task that was running and let the ECS Service spin up a new container and it started to work. I didn't dig into the logs further to see when or where something in the container got corrupted at some point, but at least for now killing and creating a new container did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

On RPM / Zip file based self-managed Confluent Platform Kafka clusters, Simply perform a rolling restart of the schema registry process on all the nodes running it one by one to resolve this.

It might happen if the schema registry instances are behind a load-balancer you may have to find out the leader host and point directly to it to get by this problem.